# How to interpret model results obtained by applying lavaan package in R?

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

Model output:
[image: Model output]

How do I interpret the ~~ operation in the model output?

The specified model is as follows:
specmod <- "

#Path c (direct effect)
PI ~ c*A_Ad

#Path a
A_Brand ~ a*A_Ad

#Path b
PI ~ b*A_Brand

#Indirect effect (a*b)
ab := a*b

"
Here, A_Ad is ad liking, A_Brand is brand liking and PI is purchase intent. The objective of the study is to measure the indirect effect of ad liking on purchase intent via the variable brand liking.

I applied the sem function in R by taking the bootstrap technique. I want to know how to interpret the model results.

Comment: https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/syntax1.html

Comment: You might have used `parameterEstimates()`. How about just using `summary()` I personally like the format of `parameterEstimates()`, which is much more efficient to read, the format of `summary()` is much easier to read for new users of lavaan. You can add "ci = TRUE" when calling `summary()` to get the bootstrap CIs.

Answer (score 0):

What is unclear?

A summary:

This is a mediation, row 2 tells us that seeing the ad increases brand liking by .49 on average, and row 3 tells us that in turn each step of increased brand liking increases purchase intention by .64 on average. The indirect effect (ab) shows that this  is a significant mediation, and that the mediated effect is .31. The confidence intervals don't include 0, which means that you can be 95% confident that this effect is not 0.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I would also like to understand what does the 4th, 5th and 6th row signify.

Comment: Have you checked the page @Terrence posted? It explained the meaning of the `~~` operator.

Comment: Rows 4, 5, and 6 show the variance of each variable in the model. For endogenous variables, it is the residual variance (that is not explained by exogenous variables).